# Create string in a new column dependent on partial string match

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe which currently contains one column called name but I would like to add another column called group containing strings "both", "one", or "neither" depending on the strings in the existing name column.

The column "name" contains a combination of two codes (I have 15 codes in total).

- If **one** of the two codes is ano, tuk, or wai I would like to pass the string "one" into the new group column.
- If **neither** of codes is ano, tuk, or wai I would like to pass the string "neither" into the new group column.
- If **both** of the codes are ano, tuk, or wai I would like to pass the string "both" into the new group column.

I tried ifelse but am still not sure how to add an argument to pass the string "both". For example, I would like the second row of the dataframe "ano tuk" to return "both" rather than "one".

```
data <- data.frame(name=c("ano ngo", "ano tuk", "ngo bon", "bon wai"))

data$group <- ifelse(grepl("ano", data$name, ignore.case = T), "one", 
                  ifelse(grepl("tuk", data$name, ignore.case = T), "one",
                         ifelse(grepl("wai", data$name, ignore.case = T), "one","neither")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `case_when()` here, along with `grepl()`:

```r
data$group <- case_when(
                  grepl("^(?:ano|tuk|wai) (ano|tuk|wai)$",
                        data$name, ignore.case=TRUE) ~ "both",
                  grepl("\\b(?:ano|tuk|wai)\\b", data$name, ignore.case=TRUE) ~ "one",
                  TRUE ~ "neither")
```